# How to include NULL or None values for the "IN" clause query in pymongo?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I want find the paths in mongodb which also contains None values if path is not present in database.

But problem is "IN" clause query only consider values which exists.

Here is my code.

```
veye_path = [path['dir_path'] for path in veye_db.find({"uuid": {"$in": binary_veye_uuid}})]
```

I also want to include None values as well.

Comment: You can use `None` in your PyMongo query.

Comment: Provide a small amount of data from the `veye_db` collection and identify which records are not working

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
{'$or': [{"uuid": {"$in": binary_veye_uuid},{"uuid": {"$exists": false}]}
```

Comment: {"uuid": {"$exists": false}  it will check whole database for None values but I want records of previous day.

Comment: Add additional conditions as needed.